# How to make separate EFI bootloader entries for Linux Mint and Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, linux-mint, grub2, uefi

When I install a GRUB bootloader entry (with `grub-install --target=x86_64-efi --efi-directory=/boot/efi /dev/sda`) from Linux Mint to my hard disk, it overrides my Ubuntu bootloader entry in EFI. To be clear what I mean by "bootloader entry" is what is shown when I press F9. What is shown is a list of bootloaders (which I'll call the 'bootloader menu'), each belonging to different distributions. Like there's one for Ubuntu, another for Debian, another for openSUSE, another for PCLinuxOS, *etc.* When I select one a unique GRUB menu is shown, from which I can boot the distribution to which the menu belongs, or another distribution, but the distribution to which the menu belongs would be the default distribution booted (e.g. if I selected 'pclinuxos' from the bootloader menu I could boot PCLinuxOS from this GRUB menu, or another distribution, but PCLinuxOS would be default).

Unfortunately Linux Mint's bootloader is also named as 'ubuntu'. So whenever I installed it, it will override the bootloader installed by Ubuntu. Is there a way to have two separate bootloaders belonging to these distributions, one for Ubuntu and another for Mint?

EDIT: If you are unclear on what I am saying run `efibootmgr` on a EFI system and it'll list what I mean by "bootloader entry". For me it lists:

```
BootCurrent: 0002
Timeout: 0 seconds
BootOrder: 0001,3001,0002,0003,0004,0005,0006,0007,2001,2002,2003
Boot0000* Notebook Hard Drive
Boot0001* ubuntu
Boot0002* debian
Boot0003* arch
Boot0004* pclinuxos
Boot0005* opensuse
Boot0006* neon
Boot2001* USB Drive (UEFI)
Boot2002* Internal CD/DVD ROM Drive (UEFI)
Boot3001* Internal Hard Disk or Solid State Disk
```

This is distinct from GRUB boot entries, which you can list by running `cat /boot/grub/grub.cfg`. What I want is for there to be an entry in this efibootmgr list belonging to Mint and another belonging to Ubuntu.

Comment: Edit the (wrong) Ubuntu text to Mint in grub.cfg ( In PCLinuxOS2017 the file is `/boot/grub2/grub.cfg` ).

Comment: Sorry, it is difficult to make what I mean completely clear. What I want relates more to entries in /boot/efi/EFI than /boot/grub2/grub.cfg. I don't want to edit GRUB entries. `efibootmgr` lists what I want to change.